# SharePoint how to ensure user in spfx

Tags: development, spfx, 2019, pnpjs

I have a question regarding SharePoint development. I'm working on a SPFX webpart for SP2019, the webpart is going to retrieve data from external source and the data will contain AD users. In my webpart I would like to show the Name of the user instead of his AD account. How can I achieve that exactly?

So the value that I get is domain\username.

I got so far that I can get the user display name with pnp js sp.web.siteusers and loginame like so "i:0#.w|domain\username" , so it is basically from _api/web/siteusers. BUT the problem is, that ofcourse I do not see all the users there that are in AD.

For example, I know that user has rights to access the site, but he never visited it, so I could not find his login in siteusers.

I tried as well the sp.web.ensureuser() but the thing i have to pass is a bit different what I have... and again it says that it will add the user to the web, what is not really needed as wel. I just need to get the name.

So how exactly, can I then get the name of the user or a group?

Comment: looks the same question. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/244758/spfx-get-user-id-from-user-login-name

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [@pnp/sp/profiles](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/profiles/)

Gets properties for a specified user

```
const loginName = "i:0#.f|membership|testuser@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com";
const profile = await sp.profiles.getPropertiesFor(loginName);
console.log(profile.DisplayName);
console.log(profile.Email);
console.log(profile.Title);
console.log(profile.UserProfileProperties.length);

// Properties are stored in inconvenient Key/Value pairs,
// so parse into an object called userProperties
var props = {};
profile.UserProfileProperties.forEach((prop) => {
  props[prop.Key] = prop.Value;
});

profile.userProperties = props;
console.log("Account Name: " + profile.userProperties.AccountName);
```

Comment: yes that is what I thought as wel, but the loginname... i don't have it in that kind of format, for example I don't get the email of the user i only have his login name in format domain\username... what to do then?

Comment: I think you need to convert the format of loginname by substring or split functions.

Comment: so even if it is not online, it has to be membership|testuser@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com, :/

Comment: Yes, indeed the user name I can retrieve like that but ... what to do with the AD Group? how to manage that? Or how to verify it?